# Which is correct and what's the difference: "Next time I'll need <something>, I'll ...", or "Next time I need <something>, I'll"?

Tags: future

English is not my native language, so I've question about using the future tense. Which is correct:

```
Next time I'll need <something>, I'll ...
```

or

```
Next time I need <something>, I'll ...
```

Are they different at all? What is the difference? I can't feel any difference. Which one is correct?

Comment: The first one is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Next time I need , I'll ...* is correct.

If you write *Next time I'll need , I'll ...*, you're saying that when you have a *future* meed, you'll ... - but you're not giving a specific time.

For instance, next time I need live bait, I'm going to buy red worms. I'm probably not going fishing until next year, but I know that I'll need live bait. Therefore the next time "I'll need live bait" is right now. The next time "I need live bait" is when I'm heading out with a fish pole.  I need to buy live bait then, not now.

Comment: This is going to take a while to process. :) Re-reading and re-reading. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you expand the sentences you get:

1. Next time I will need something, I will
2. Next time I need something, I will

Sentence 1. doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: They both make sense...

Comment: Second @bodacydo - you can say for instance, "Next time I'll need brain surgery, if I come to ELU for English suggestions."  This is not the same as "The next time I need brain surgery, I hope my surgeon can read the manual ..."

Comment: @HowardPautz - your example doesn't actually support the contradiction of 5arx's answer.

Comment: @medica - I'm unsure why you think so, but please do clarify what you see as errant in my comment.

Comment: Your construction does not parallel what you purport it does. *Next time I'll need brain surgery* ***if*** is very different from *Next time I'll need brain surgery* ***I'll***...

Comment: @medica - oops bad editor (me) there's a typo in them thar comments - didn't even notice! "Next time I'll need brain surgery, I'll " is indeed the correct version. Too bad we can't edit comments > 5mins. oh well. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Make it fit your assertion...

Comment: @bodacydo - I concede that #1 makes sense, but its certainly an odd construction. The first 'will' has the appearance of a conditional clause but isn't. It reads marginally better if you insert a comma after 'time'. But even then I suspect it would be pruned by a proofreader if it appeared in copy. And I doubt a competent or native speaker would ever employ such a sentence.

Answer (score -1):

next time I need [something], I'll...

next time [clause], [sentence]

"Next time..." is a conditional clause that describes the sentence's verb happens. the clause itself doesn't necessarily happen, and you are not implying that it is going to happen.

that is why you can't use "will".

you could also think of it as a cause and effect clause.

like in math? P->Q? but not Q <-P

if [I need something] then [I'll...].

you aren't saying you will need something, you are saying what you will do **IF** you need something.

### **About the Helper Verb "Will"**:

if you know Spanish or a similar language, it's kind of like the subjunctive. 
**Using "will" or "I'll" implies that something is going happen.** You **know** that it's going to happen.

If you use "will" while you are not completely sure, it implies that you believe that something will happen.

In your example, you aren't saying you "**will** need " you're saying "**if** you need [something]"

**Examples:**

***I'll*...** < = this happens in the future **for sure**.

-

***I'll* probably...** < = ***CORRECT***, likely to happen, **you believe** it will happen.

**I'll might...**  < = ***WRONG***, may or may not happen.

-

**If the sky falls tomorrow, I'll hide under my bed.**   < = **if** the sky falls

**The sky *will* fall tomorrow, I'll hide under my bed.** < = **when** the sky falls

-

**Next Time we get pizza, I'll get cheese.** < = **might** happen

**Next week *we'll* get pizza, I'll get cheese.** < = this is **definitely** going  to happen.